# regex expresion to identify digits and remove comma

Tags: regex

I have what I though a simple case yet I'm unable to find solution.
Simple text

```
this is number 88 and rest of the text
```

from which I'd like to extract all digits (88 in this case) is simple \d+ or [0-9]+ and I'm done.
The problem is that sometimes I have the text in a below form with comma:

```
this is number 2,563 and rest of the text
```

and when I apply either of the above pattern it leaves me with 2 565 - with a space in-between two and five which at the end cause new line so

```
2
563
```

after I export it into excel.
Problem is that I'm using custom tool (not programming language ) that excepts text as an input, regex pattern and export the output.
This is why I need single pattern that eliminate space and produce either 88 or 2563 or any other number. The commas are every 3 positions obviously, so it can also be 1,345,321 as well as just single number 5 between "this is number .... and rest of the text"

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: What operations is your tool capable of performing? Just *match* or *replace* as well?

Comment: You say "a simple case" then on to say thousands separator, then on to say a single number. There are hundreds of solutions. Before, after, what is a number, what is the boundary's, on and on and on. What expectations ? It's up to you to define that. Why ask for expectations amid the hundreds of possibilities that you are not close to defining? `[,\d]+` is really as good as `^(?|(\d{1,3}(?=([.,\h])?)(?:\2\d{3})*)(?:(?!\2)[.,](\d*))|(\d+)()(?:[.,](\d*))?|()()[.,](\d+))$`
https://regex101.com/r/NrAasX/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
\b\d+(?:,\d+)*
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/YeTOo4/1).
You did not specify your programming language (if any) but this works with most engines.